# xcodebuild: No valid iOS Distribution signing identities belonging to team

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build and create IPA but I'm getting this error:

```
Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "No valid iOS Distribution signing identities belonging to team XXXXXXXXX were found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No valid iOS Distribution signing identities belonging to team XXXXXXXXX were found.}
```

I can archive just fine but this is how I'm trying to create the IPA:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <xcarchivepath> 
-exportPath <destinationpath>
-exportOptionsPlist <plistpath>
```

I can generate the IPA using xcode just fine but my question to guys is how can generate the IPA without having this issue with the certificate?, do I need to export the certificate ?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: If you are using XCode 8.3
Take a look at this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75038

Comment: @MohnishHirudkar , I tried PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="XXXXXXXXX" where XXXXXXXXX is my apple developer ID (Alpha numeric value) but still have the same error

Comment: I had the same problem and the easiest way I found to fix it was to use fastlane and gym.